# Converting to UNIX time, what am I doing wrong here?

Tags: python, datetime, unix, pytz

After reading a few SO articles about converting to UNIX/Epoch time from a normal `datetime`, I am still confused. Can someone explain what I'm not seeing here:

```
import time
from datetime import datetime
import dateutil.parser
import pytz

tz_LA = pytz.timezone('America/Los_Angeles')
tz_DV = pytz.timezone('America/Denver')

date_start_naive = '2017-04-16T00:00:00'
date_end_naive = '2017-04-16T23:59:59'

# Convert the ISO-8601 time into epoch time:
date_start_LA = tz_LA.localize(dateutil.parser.parse(date_start_naive))
date_start_DV = tz_DV.localize(dateutil.parser.parse(date_start_naive))
date_end = dateutil.parser.parse(date_end_naive)

print(date_start_LA.strftime('%s'))
print(date_start_DV.strftime('%s'))
print(date_end.strftime('%s'))
```

which produces:

```
>>> 1492322400
>>> 1492322400
>>> 1492408799
```

forgive my naivety, but shouldn't the first two integers be an hour different since `2017-04-16T00:00:00` in LA is `2017-04-16T01:00:00` in Denver?

Comment: You should probably start by seperating out the `dateutil.parser.parse` call and make sure that's giving you want you want.

Comment: What version of Python are you using that %s is a valid format string? The documentation for Python 2.7 and 3.6 don't include that.

Comment: @Paul You're right. I was using an SO answer that wasn't right. `%s` is a bad way to format as Epoch time. It uses your system time (which is localized to your system). You should use `.timestamp()` instead and it gets the right answer.